# Call Google Play Developer API from Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-play-console, google-developers-console

I followed  [Google Play Developer API setup documentation](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started) to connect my Flutter app to Google API.

The app in Google play console is now connected to the project in Google Cloud Platform, so my question how Call Google Play Developer API from Flutter app and get the app details like published app version.

I didn't find any valuable documentation about calls between Flutter app and Google play API. I didn't have any information about Google API. I want to see if the connection is correct and how to get response from the API.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an immediate update or flexible update feature. Then kindly use this library. [in_app_update](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_update)

Comment: I need to call Google play API from my Flutter APP, how?